# How to embed googlebooks search api in view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-books

I have a code `GoogleBooks.search('The Great Gatsby')` of [this gem](https://github.com/zeantsoi/GoogleBooks) that I can work out from command-line. But how do I make search possible from a textfield in view?. One way I know is having a controller action do it for me.. but was just wondering if there is better option and live search would be a plus!

Thanks.